# How to pause a certain code and run another until needed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a pokemon game from scratch and I've got far enough till every time I click my attack option it will run the first if statement then run the next if statement replacing the first picture before giving me a chance to run the next time is their a way I can run the first if statement without it conflicting with the second if statement? I posted the link to my code

```js
if (humanchoice === "effective") {
  let BOT = document.createElement("img")
  BOT.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Jys5bTaWg_ZRBr9GwE1CJ-4XzNWOsgp64aX0g1yXJ5UaMBE0vuuLO-OcIDDN7LNfKbH2ovFhwkyb2cKuiyhbKYUtuRDy-OOxNWVz6pEMIgRMim-LF0HHg-gMj1x-n8fJMAqaf8Y_=w246-h41-p-k'
  BOT.className = 'overlappedEnemyHealth'
  document.body.appendChild(BOT)
  console.log(BOT)
  if (BOT.src === 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Jys5bTaWg_ZRBr9GwE1CJ-4XzNWOsgp64aX0g1yXJ5UaMBE0vuuLO-OcIDDN7LNfKbH2ovFhwkyb2cKuiyhbKYUtuRDy-OOxNWVz6pEMIgRMim-LF0HHg-gMj1x-n8fJMAqaf8Y_=w246-h41-p-k' && humanchoice === "effective") {
    BOT.src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Yy8PPjNdJqTl8cmGTD81PzPBt3arn4358tGjNOR4iEkpe9s6c5beV7UBN-QPeSNypgMt2-nJKGwn0T46g4HkJtwx9e4lCk_fV8LPNq0OR0k7CmE5Wg_6eq0-I56M4zAjZp1-Vk86=w246-h41-p-k"
    console.log(BOT)
  }
} else if (botchoice === "super effective") {} 
  else if (humanchoice === "not effective") {}

console.log(humanchoice)
console.log(botchoice)
}


function fightch() {
}

function fightchance() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}

function fightchoiceYou(choice) {
  return ["effective", "super effective", "not effective"][choice]
}

function fightchanceBot() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}

function fightchoiceBot(choice) {
  return ["effective", "super effective", "not effective"][choice]
}
```

https://codepen.io/jsmirga22/pen/ZEBEbNY

Comment: Here is your logic: if effective then create img and set it's source x then if img source is x and effective change the source of the image. <--- Your second/inner `if` statement tests for conditions you just set in code above it. Since you just set those that `if` will always be true and will always immediately change the image to something else.

Comment: is there a way to make it not always be true

Comment: You have to explain the logic you expect to occur. Why and when would you expect the image to change? Under what circumstances.